# Output perl debugger only to a file and not to the console

Tags: perl, debugging

(This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164359/debugging-perl-scripts-without-interactive-debugger/) question I asked recently)

I'm using the perl debugger non-interactively like this:

```
PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop=1 LineInfo=/path/to/perl_log AutoTrace=0" perl -d big_confusing_script.pl $some $args
```

But in addition to writing the output to the log, it's also printing these 100s of lines to the console, which makes it very hard to see whether or not changes i'm making are messing up the flow of the larger shell script this perl script is a part of, and thus making it hard to create an effective debug workflow.

I'd like to know if it's possible to get this debug info to only be logged to the file and not written to the console. Is this possible with another PERLDB_OPTS flag? Or do I have to redirect stderr to /dev/null when invoking perl or something? Note that for the tool to work, the Perl's normal printing to stdout needs to be unaffected.

Comment: Can't reproduce -- for me it's not writing debug output to the terminal, only script's normal `STDOUT` (debug goes to the file)

Comment: Yes `LineInfo=file.txt` seems to work fine here too as mentioned by @zdim. Can you show a minimal example of the problem? See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score -2):

You can direct STDOUT to a file like this:

```
perl program.pl > out.txt
```

And you can do the same for STDERR like this:

```
perl program.pl 2> err.txt
```

You can also use them together like this:

```
perl program.pl > out.txt 2> err.txt
```

Instead of using the Perl Debugger to output to the file, try:

```
PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop=1 AutoTrace=0" perl -d big_confusing_script.pl $some $args > /path/to/perl_log
```

Comment: Downvote because this doesn't answer the question of treating the output of the script itself and the debugger separately.